# Same value gets set for a cookie in multiple Chrome tabs despite different URLs

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

My Angular application URL structure is as below:

```
    Domain/clientCode/*
```

And the backend API which is a Node application is setting cookie as below:

Fetch clientCode from the URL and set cookie as:

```
    response.cookie('client', clientCode, { httpOnly: true });
```

Now the problem is When we open Multiple client URIs in different browser tabs (Chrome) in Quick succession, all the tabs get same value for client cookie. If we open different client tabs once pervious one gets loaded then cookie is setting properly for each tab.

Example:

When we open below URLs in different tabs in Chrome in quick succession:

- Domain/ABC/*
- Domain/BCD/*
- Domain/DEF/*
- Domain/XYZ/*

The client cookie has same value for multiple tabs(We want it to be different for each tab as per the clientCode in the URL).
I know that cookies are saved for a domain and doesn't consider other values in the URL but Its working fine when we open multiple URLs with little bit of gap.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are setting a static cookie for your domain. You need to set dynamic cookies to avoid the issue.

For example: You may set the cookie name for the username = 'Michelle' with random dynamic values like `Michelle_456900234`. For each login session, you will have a dynamic value associated with it. While retrieving the value just find the substring username.

Comment: The problem is, the Module we are accessing here doesn't need user to be authenticated. The contents are publicly accessible.